# What is the voltage across the capacitor at t=infiniti in this circuit?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, circuit-analysis

[image]

Hi, I just want to verify my answer for a). Is Vc(infinite)=10V since it open circuited at t=infinite? Or do I need to use voltage division to find Vc?

Comment: The voltage source is AC source, so the steady state voltage across the capacitor will also be AC voltage. And for sure not equal to 10V. Because the capacitor is a open circuit only at DC

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So do I have to use a voltage division to find Vc infinite? or what do I have to do?

Comment: Strictly speaking the correct answer is \$v_C(\infty)\$ is undefined, which in other words means the question is badly formulated. Once transient has expired \$v_C=V_{max}\sin(\omega\, t + \varphi)\$ and limit for \$t\rightarrow\infty\$ is not defined for sine functions. Finding \$V_{max}\$ and \$\varphi\$ is what, in my opinion, is closest to answering point (a)

Comment: Where does this example come from? (a) no units for resistors; should be Ohm (b) frequency should be Hz, not rad/sec;

Comment: It's my teacher's question.... he makes the hardest questions...

Answer (score 1):

Remember that infinity is **not** a number. So, as \$\small t\rightarrow \infty\$ all the transients can be considered dissipated, and all that remain are the steady-state signals - in this case, a sinusoid.

The capacitor can certainly not be considered an open circuit at large values of time. It will always be subject to a sinusoidal forcing function.

A steady-state frequency response analysis (\$\small s\rightarrow j\omega\$, for example) will give the voltage across the capacitor for \$\small t\rightarrow \infty\$.

Comment: Thank you! My teacher is giving me such hard questions when he didn't even teach that in class >< so i don't know what to do...